# C# trim within the get; set;

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, trim

I am total MVC newbie coming from 10 years of webforms.  Here is the code I have inherited:

```
namespace sample.Models
{
    public class Pages
    {
        public int PageID { get; set; }
        public string FolderName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I apply a trim function to the "set" portion of this code?  Right now it is allowing spaces at the end of foldername and I need to prevent that.

Okay I have incorporated the suggestions however the spaces are still getting saved.
Here are the UI/ vs Database.  The UI is trimming properly but the full value with spaces is stored in the table:

[image: UI]

[image: Database has spaces]

Answer (score 27):

You need a [backing field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx):

```
public class Pages
{
    public int PageID { get; set; }

    private string _folderName;
    public string FolderName 
    { 
        get { return _folderName; } 
        set { _folderName = value.Trim(); }
    }
}
```

In the setter method we use the `Trim` string's method, which

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

For further info regarding this method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Brilliant, I will try that - thanks for quick reply!

Comment: not to detract from the answer, but OP should be aware that he'll need to  handle `null` cases appropriately

Comment: You may want to consider using an extension method that implements Trim with a null check to handle null case.

Comment: @WesDoyle: or just use C# 6's null conditional operator `_folderName = value?.Trim();`

Comment: That works great in the UI but it is still creating a folder with the spaces and saving the spaces to the table.  I

 am not even sure where the Insert/Update SQL code is found

Comment: @user2055729 Do you want to remove ALL whitespaces or only leading and trailing?

Comment: @user2055729 thank you. When you say it works great in the UI what do you mean.  Could you please provide an example (input/output). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2055729 You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped :) By the way what was the problem?

Answer (score 5):

What about this solution:

```
    public class Pages
    {
         private string _folderName;

         public int PageID { get; set; }

         public string FolderName
         {
              get { return _folderName; }
              set { _folderName = value?.Trim() ?? string.Empty; }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may consider writing a custom extension method to call Trim only if the value of your string is not null:

```
public static class CustomExtensions
{
     public static string TrimIfNotNull(this string value)
     {
         if (value != null)
         {
             value = value.Trim();
         }
         return value;
     }
}
```

And then in your `Pages` class, something like

```
private string _folderName;
public string FolderName
{
    get { return _folderName.TrimIfNotNull(); }
    set { _folderName = value.TrimIfNotNull(); }
}
```

If you're using C#6, as mentioned by Jacob Krall, you can use the null conditional operator directly and not worry about the extension method:

```
public string FolderName 
{ 
    get { return _folderName; } 
    set { _folderName = value?.Trim(); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The shorthand syntax for properties is only for when you want to provide a thin layer of abstraction on top of a field. If you want to manipulate the field within the getter or setter, you need to specify the backing field on your own.

```
namespace sample.Models
{
    public class Pages
    {
        public int PageID { get; set; }

        private string folderName;
        public string FolderName 
        { 
            get { return folderName; }
            set { folderName = value.Trim(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Pages
{
    public int PageId { get; set; }

    // you need a backing field then you can customize the set and get code
    private string folderName;
    public string FolderName
    {
        get { return this.folderName; }

        // if the fileName can be set to null you'll want to use ?. or you'll get 
        // a null reference exception
        set { this.folderName = value?.Trim(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Know this is an old post, but this introduces a subtle bug where the value is left unchanged if 'FolderName' is set to null.

Comment: What bug? The original post only said they wanted to trim spaces, not prevent null from being assigned. If you assign null then folderName will be null. If you assign a string value then folderName will be the trimmed string value.

Comment: If you assign null, the 'this.folderName' is unchanged.  See @MagicUser123's answer.

Comment: See my prev response. It'll only be left "unchanged" if you try to assign null and the prev value was also null. But that may be what you want. The OP never specified that it couldn't be null. The OP only specified that they wanted to trim spaces, not that they wanted to avoid assigning a null value.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below. 
//You can filter the entry before saving it into the database.

```
          //About the null issue. You can use this.

          if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtusername.Text))
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot be blank!");
            }

        //You can filter the entry before saving it into the database

        txtpageid.Text = book.PageID.Trim();
        txtfoldername.Text = book.FolderName.Trim();
```